# How to install npm dependencies inside a sub directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a `package.json` in the root: `"install": "cd packages/my-package && yarn"`.

When I run `yarn run install` all I'm asking is that it goes into this package, installs the `node_modules` and dependencies and that's it. For some reason no matter what I try (yarn workspaces/lerna/manually etc.) it is installing `node_modules` in all packages, including the root.

WHY?! Just let me install them separately :(

Anyone knows how to easily fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To move the basefolder of node_modules, you will have to create a `.yarnrc` file in the same directory as your package.json file. Your `.yarnrc` file should look like

```
--modules-folder packages/my-packages
```

The resulting output will put all of your packages after my-packages
`/packages/my-packages/WHERE_YOUR_PACKAGES_GO`